# Vue router with sub path

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have following component for the url:

```
  {
    path: '/resetpassword',
    name: 'view-resetpassword',
    component: ViewResetPassword,
  },
```

And it gets opened when I enter `localhosst:8080/resetpassword`

My question is how to access parameters that are given in that way:

`localhost:8080/resetpassword/53c957fe-bbc2-4b32-8ebd-a84d79f7ffd2`

I know, that I can access URL paramaters `?key=value` with `this.$route.query.key` in the code. But how do I access parameter `/...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your router to:

```js
{
  path: '/resetpassword/:token?',
  name: 'view-resetpassword',
  component: ViewResetPassword,
},
```

That route now can have optional `token` param (`?` is for the optional).
Then you can access it on your component

```js
this.$route.params.token
```

You can also pass it as a props instead, by adding `props: true` on the router

```js
{
  path: '/resetpassword/:token?',
  name: 'view-resetpassword',
  component: ViewResetPassword,
  props: true
},
```

and on your component

```
export default {
  ...
  props: ["token"];
  ...
}
```

then you can access the props

```js
this.token
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use, like this

```
{ name: 'Projeto', path: '/projeto/:id', component: Projeto, meta: { public: true } }
```

with the :(the name), in the component:

```
this.$route.params.id
```

In my example is id, but you can put another name

A page to example [VueRouter](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html)

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes), proceed as so:

```
{
  path: '/resetpassword/:id',  // I changed here
  name: 'view-resetpassword',
  component: ViewResetPassword,
}
```

Then in the matched component, you can access the parameter through `$route.params.id`.